# Prove that $s$ is the supremum of a nonempty subset of the real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I have to prove the following proposition. Suppose $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $A$ is nonempty and bounded above. Prove that if $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,s+\frac{1}{n}$ is an upper bound for $A$ and $s-\frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound for $A$, then $s=\operatorname{sup} A$.

(Where $\operatorname{sup}A$, is a real number satisfying: i) $\operatorname{sup}A$ is an upper bound for $A$, meaning that for any $a\in A$, $a\le\operatorname{sup}A$; and ii) $\operatorname{sup}A$ is the least upper bound, meaning that for all $b\in\mathbb{R}$, if for every $a\in A$, $a\le b$, then $\operatorname{sup}A\le b$.)

*Proof*. First we show that $s$ is an upper bound. Suppose $s$ is not an upper bound, then we can choose an $a_0\in A$ such that $s<a_0$. By the Archimedean Property, we can choose an $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $\frac{1}{n_0}<a_0-s$, which is equivalent to $s+\frac{1}{n_0}<a_0$, but this contradicts the fact that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\forall a\in A(a\le s+\frac{1}{n})$. Hence, we can conclude that $s$ is an upper bound for $A$.

Now we prove that $s$ is the least upper bound. Suppose there is an upper bound $b$ for $A$ such that $b<s$, that is, $s$ is not the least upper bound. By the Archimedean Property, there is an $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $s-b>\frac{1}{n_0}$. We know that for any $a\in A$, $a-b\le0$, and that $0<s-b-\frac{1}{n_0}$, combining both expressions we have: $a-b
\le0<s-b-\frac{1}{n_0}$, i.e., $a<s-\frac{1}{n_0}$, contradicting the fact that $s-\frac{1}{n_0}$ for any natural number $n$ is not an upper bound for $A$. Therefore, we can claim that $s$ is the least upper bound, $s=\operatorname{sup}A$. $\square$

Is this proof right?

Thank you.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP could answer it by looking up the definition of supremum.